# GlusterFS server logic

Tags: filesystems, nfs, glusterfs, distributed-filesystems

I quite don't understand about GlusterFS probes. See, i add all servers to /etc/hosts file and i do this for each server. Lets say i have 100 servers and later i added 100 more. I cannot imagine updating all 200 server's hosts file for see each others.

Is there something that i missed here? How can i easily add more servers without modify each servers hosts file?

Should I use private LAN and use IP addresses instead of hostnames? Will this work?

Stuck at this point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GlusterFS documentation](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Storage%20Pools/) states:

> The servers used to create the storage pool must be resolvable by hostname.

So no you can't use IP Adresses here. You can either add each server to `/etc/hosts` or setup a private DNS server like `bind`.

If you administrate 100+ servers it is time to think about a `configuration management` solution. Beside editing `/etc/hosts` such system can also install `GlusterFS` on the nodes. I prefere `Ansible`, other popular solutions include `Puppet`, `Chef`, etc.

Comment: thanks for heads up. Now i understand. I should read documentations more carefully... my bad.